# ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0] is legal ruby grammar?

Tags: ruby

[In this post](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/01/migrations-are-versioned-in-rails-5.html), I don't understand why `ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]` class name doesn't throw a syntax error. Is that a legal ruby grammar? or what hack used with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's perfectly legal - it calls the class method `[]` for the `ActiveRecord::Migration` class. Have a look at [the implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L526).

Answer (score 2):

[] is a class method of the [Migration class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta2/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L526)

**Edit** 
@eugen was a bit quicker than me :-)

Comment: Chose @eugen's answer because he is little bit faster. But thank you. :)